# How to load all custom taxonomy terms in sidebar like categories

Tags: wordpress

I want to display all custom taxonomy terms in the sidebar of my website and when click on each display all of its posts. any help
**Novice to Wordpress**
your help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-custom-taxonomy-widget/ this plugin helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use get_taxonomies()

See : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for replying .
I solved it like this:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'taxonomy'=>'product_category',
    'parent' => 0
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
}
```

May help others.